# Subtheme for Subsite in Multisite

Tags: theming, multi-sites

I have a Drupal 8 Multisite setup with the following Folder structure:

- themes

  - custom_theme

    - main_custom_theme
- sites

  - site1

    - themes

      - subtheme1
  - site 2

So I want both sites to use main_custom_theme, but site1 needs to override one template (page.html.twig) with subtheme1. subtheme1 folder contains a subtheme1.info.yml as follows:

```
name: subtheme1
description: "Custom sub-theme"
core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: main_custom_theme
```

I rebuilt all caches (Backend and drush cr, but drush cr might not clean caches of subsites?) but cannot select the new subtheme in Backend of site1.
What am I missing?

---

This is the Twig Debug output after using leymannx answer, subsites path is "leistungen"

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--leistungen.html.twig
   * page--node--560.html.twig
   * page--node--%.html.twig
   * page--node--article.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   x page.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/my_custom_theme/templates/main/page.html.twig' -->
```

---

I have a question that builds on this one... I published it appearently with a different user, without wanting to. Still new to not only reading stackexchange :)

If I try to do the same for the node of my content type, which is using a template named node--CONTENTTYPENAME.html.twig at the moment, I can insert a name suggestion node--NAMEOFSUBSITE.html.twig, which will then be used for ALL nodes. I'd like to insert a suggestion such as node--CONTENTYPENAME--NAMEOFSUBSITE.html.twig, for only this one nodetype.

How can I do that?

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: So inside `themes/custom/my_custom_theme/templates/main` there is a `page--leistungen.html.twig`?

Comment: It is inside themes/custom/my_custom_theme/templates/main . That's also where the used page.html.twig is located.

Comment: And did you try to put it into `themes/custom/my_custom_theme/templates` as well? Really strange then. I'd say it's caching. But you said you already flushed all Drupal caches.

Comment: Yes I did, on all subsites in Backend, with `drush cr` and `drush -l leistungen cache:rebuild` I think it's caching, too. But wondering, why other template changes are recognized? It's weird.

Comment: Gosh, we must miss something. There must be a typo or something. The suggestion is there, so it MUST pick up the template. Why wouldn't it pick up the template? ( •́ ⍨ •̀)

Comment: I am not quite sure why, but restarting docker and local dev system: It works!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 you are supposed to organize your themes and multi-site instances like in the following structure. I only highlight the relevant folders.

```
__docroot
  |__modules
  |  |__contrib
  |  |  |__devel
  |  |  |__views
  |  |__custom
  |     |__my_module_abc
  |     |__my_module_xyz
  |__sites
  |  |__default
  |  |  |__settings.php
  |  |__site1
  |  |  |__settings.php
  |  |__site2
  |     |__settings.php
  |__themes
     |__contrib
     |  |__bootstrap
     |__custom
        |__my_bootstrap_subtheme
```

So, if you want to create a sub-theme of a custom theme, you also have to place it inside `docroot/themes/custom`. Then it will appear in your back-end where you can enable it.

---

But what I would recommend instead of adding another sub-theme, is to simply add a template suggestion based on the multi-site instance name via [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x). By that you can move on with only one custom theme (which is much easier to maintain in the end), and inside its `MYTHEME.theme` file you'll switch the page template for your certain multi-site instance like following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  $site_path = \Drupal::service('site.path');
  $site_path = explode('/', $site_path);
  $site_name = $site_path[1];

  $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $site_name;
}
```

Now you simply can place `page--site1.html.twig` in your theme's template folder and `site1` will take this page template instead the default `page.html.twig`. ([Source](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-07-02/how-to-add-in-drupal-8-a-custom-suggestion-page-template))

---

Tried it on a fresh D8 with [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) enabled and it works just fine.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x page--site1.html.twig
   * page--front.html.twig
   * page--node--1.html.twig
   * page--node--%.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/my-custom-subtheme/templates/page--site1.html.twig' -->
```