# Using template on subsite for certain node type

Tags: theming, hooks, multi-sites

I am using a custom Theme in a multisite setting. With the help of @leymannx I implemented
[hook_theme_suggestion_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) to insert a page Template with the following naming convention:
page--NAMEOFSUBSITE.html.twig

See [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/262415/subtheme-for-subsite-in-mulitsite-setting-drupal-8)

If I try to do the same for the node of my content type, which is using a template named node--CONTENTTYPENAME.html.twig at the moment, I can insert a name suggestion node--NAMEOFSUBSITE.html.twig, which will then be used for ALL nodes. I'd like to insert a suggestion such as
node--CONTENTYPENAME--NAMEOFSUBSITE.html.twig, for only this one nodetype.

How can I do that?

Thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Activate twig debug and use the browser inspector to see the template precise name available for your content-type
Do a cache rebuild when the temaplte is created to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_node_alter() should look somewhat like this:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $site_path = \Drupal::service('site.path');
  $site_path = explode('/', $site_path);
  $site_name = $site_path[1];
  $type = $variables['elements']['#node']->getType();
  $suggestions[] = 'node__'.$type.'__' . $site_name;

}
```

I found this [kint()](https://www.drupal.org/project/kint) inspecting the variables within the hook, then finding the methods defined on ['#node'].